# Neo4j Server fails to start embedded database

Tags: java, neo4j

I've created a neo4j database embedded into my java application. Creating nodes, relationships, properties and querying all of them looks fine, but now I want to visualize the database just to check if everything is okay. So I tried to load the test.db inside my neo4j-Server edition (running on the same machine), but however I get all the time the following error:

Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\user\workspace\neo4j_emb_test\target\test.db

Don't know what's going wrong here. Does anybody has suggestions?

Thanks in advance !
Julian

**edit:**

Checking the logs returned following results:

2014-05-26 14:56:30.988+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@7f180826' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@71fc9ad0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NeoStore v0.A.0' but file is version 'NeoStore v0.A.3'.
2014-05-26 14:56:30.988+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run two embedded instances against the same Neo4j database at the same time, you need to run Neo4j in stand-alone mode for that. Then you only have access to the REST API provided, and not the Java API.

I had the exact same experience a little while ago that was answered here: [Disable locking of Neo4j graph database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515778/disable-locking-of-neo4j-graph-database)

Comment: Even if I "shutdown" the database inside my application? I mean, after closing it, I tried to copy the database folder and then started the Server version, but I get the same error.
I didn't try to run both at the same time.

Comment: @user3669406 I'm not sure. You should then post some code and perhaps some error logs to pin down exactly the problem. Without any data I can only guess.

Comment: Problem solved ! Root cause was that I used the neo4j libraries from Version 2.1.0-RC2, but as server the the Community Edition 2.0.3.